# Go back button in a page

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Go Back to Previous Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548566/go-back-to-previous-page)
>   [get back to previous page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968425/get-back-to-previous-page)

How to get the previous page in javascript coding. Go to the previous page when click that back button.

Comment: My inclination is basically _don't._ The browser already has a back button, so adding a button to your page is redundant, and also if the user opened your page in a new tab or new window then you _can't_ go back.

Comment: @nnnnnn is basically correct, but there may be some situations where it may be easier to implement a back button (e.g. if the browser is running in full-screen, such as a kiosk).

Comment: possible duplicate of [get back to previous page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968425/get-back-to-previous-page) and [Go Back to Previous Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548566/go-back-to-previous-page)

Answer (score 89):

Here is the code

```
<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="window.history.back()" />
```

Answer (score 50):

You can either use:

```
<button onclick="window.history.back()">Back</button>
```

or..

```
<button onclick="window.history.go(-1)">Back</button>
```

The difference, of course, is `back()` only goes back 1 page but `go()` goes back/forward the number of pages you pass as a parameter, relative to your current page.

Answer (score 26):

There's a few ways, this is one:

```
window.history.go(-1);
```

Comment: This is great because you can also use `window.history.go(-2);` (which I just needed) or `window.history.go(-4);`, etc.

Answer (score 8):

`onclick="history.go(-1)"` Simply