# How to make a button to act as browser back button?

Tags: javascript

I am working on Joomla. I want to create a button so that if I click on that button browser redirects to previously processed page.How to make a button to act like browser's back button? This question was asked earlier here.I tried all those solutions. but none is working for me. Plaese answer this question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

```
<button onclick="window.history.back()">Go back</button>
```

Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Try the button here: http://jsfiddle.net/GTQ48/

Comment: Nice, the original answer got a downvote...

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript button:

```
<button onclick="window.history.go(-1)">Back</button>
```

Source: [Go back button in a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511679/go-back-button-in-a-page)

Comment: -1 for copying my answer.

Comment: Actually, I got it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511679/go-back-button-in-a-page. It's a duplicate post really.

Comment: Yeah, but still, should've left your original one. It's not cool.

Comment: My apologies, I'm still new here :)

Comment: @shomz...that solution is not working for me.that is why I posted the question again.So that I could find some new solutions.Butttt :(