# Cant navigate to right page URL using window.history.go(-1)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using plain javascript, HTML and `history.go(-1)` method to navigate to last visited page url.

***Expected result***: Navigate to last visited page URL after click.

***Existing result***: After click it navigates to homepage not previous visited page URL, page title changes correctly but page url not updating.

Console shows no errors. Already tried:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

[onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)" not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253035/onclick-javascripthistory-go-1-not-working-in-chrome)

[Onclick javascript to make browser go back to previous page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067510/onclick-javascript-to-make-browser-go-back-to-previous-page)

[get back to previous page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968425/get-back-to-previous-page)

**Code**:

```
<a href="/" onclick="goToPreviousPage();"></a>

<script>
    function goToPreviousPage() {
       history.go(-1);
       return false;
    }
</script>
```

Adding `#` to `href` attribute to prevent going to home:

```
<a href="#" onclick="goToPreviousPage();"></a>
```

or

```
<button onclick="goToPreviousPage();">Go back</button>
```

it just reloads the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preventDefault()` to stop default action

Try this :

```
<a href="/" onclick="goToPreviousPage();">est</a>

<script>
 function goToPreviousPage() {
  event.preventDefault();
  history.go(-1);
  return false;
 }
</script>
```

Comment: After that getting console error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

Comment: Updated, please check, need to use `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Console error gone, but result is the same as without event.preventDeault();

Comment: It works great here :|, can you able to provide jsfiddle

Comment: In jsfiddle works this code snippet, something is wrong with code in another place which cause this behavior

Comment: Maybe some confliction